# Passing JSON Data into Android JAVA String

Tags: java, android, json

I want to Load data as String variable from JSON in Java android studio. 
My JSON is :

```
{
    "server_response": [
        {
            "name": "1",
            "email": "istiyak.pro@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "990-100010000"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "2",
            "email": "Tanim Khan ",
            "mobile": "tanim@gmail.com "
        }, 
        {
            "name": "3",
            "email": "Rezaul Hasan ",
            "mobile": "rezaul@gmail.com "
        }
    ]
}
```

And My target String list as Like :

```
 String email[] = {


            " Mirpur-13, Kafrul , Govt.Unani Medical College & Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Sher-E-Bangla Nagar , Shaheed Sohrawardi Medicel College Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Shahbag Square , Birdem General Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Shahbag circle , BSMMU, Dhaka",
            " Shaymoli bus stand , Dhaka Child Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Bokshi Bazar, 100 Ramna , Dhaka Medical College Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Nayabazar , Dhaka City General Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Sher-E-Bangla Nagar , National Heart Institute & Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Sher-E-Bangla Nagar, National Mental Health Institute & Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Shayamoli, Sher-E-Bangla Nagar , National Ophthalmological Institute & Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Mahakhali , National Cancer Research Institute & Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Sher-E-Bangla Nagar , National Kidney Institute & Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Sher-E-Bangla Nagar , National Orthopedics Hospital, Dhaka",
            " Mirpur , Kidney Foundation Bangladesh, Dhaka",
            " Mahakhali Kacha Bazar , ICDDRB, Dhaka"};



    String mobile[] = {

            "02-8012048",
            "02-9130800",
            "02-8616641",
            "02-9661051",
            "02-8116061",
            "02-8626812",
            "02-7390860",
            "02-9122560",
            "02-9118171",
            "02-9118336",
            "02-9880078",
            "02-91365560",
            "02-9144190",
            "02-8055827",
            "02-8806523",};
```

Now i want to set all "email" data of JSON into product[] array and "mobile" in name[] array. Please help me just how i pass data to those array.

Comment: Please post what you have tried to do to solve the problem before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `JSON Simple` from [[here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)]. Here is a [[little tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)].

Once you have downloaded it and added the jar to your project, the JSON-decoding mechanism would be something like this...

```
String st = "{\"server_response\":[{\"name\":\"1\",\"email\":\"istiyak.pro@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"990-100010000\"},{\"name\":\"2\",\"email\":\"Tanim Khan \",\"mobile\":\"tanim@gmail.com \"},{\"name\":\"3\",\"email\":\"Rezaul Hasan \",\"mobile\":\"rezaul@gmail.com \"}]}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
    Object o = parser.parse(st);
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) o;
    System.out.println(obj); // {"server_response":[{"name":"1","mobile":"990-100010000","email":"istiyak.pro@gmail.com"},{"name":"2","mobile":"tanim@gmail.com ","email":"Tanim Khan "},{"name":"3","mobile":"rezaul@gmail.com ","email":"Rezaul Hasan "}]}

    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) obj.get("server_response");

    List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> mobile = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Object each: arr) {
        JSONObject a = (JSONObject) each;
        email.add(a.get("email").toString().trim());
        mobile.add(a.get("mobile").toString().trim());
    }

    System.out.println(email); // [istiyak.pro@gmail.com, Tanim Khan, Rezaul Hasan]
    System.out.println(mobile); // [990-100010000, tanim@gmail.com, rezaul@gmail.com]

} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might notice that the `mobile` list contains things other than phone numbers. That is because of the JSON data you have provided which kinda looks like this...

```
{
    "server_response": [
        {
            "name": "1",
            "email": "istiyak.pro@gmail.com",  <--- good
            "mobile": "990-100010000"          <--- good
        }, 
        {
            "name": "2",
            "email": "Tanim Khan ",            <--- not good
            "mobile": "tanim@gmail.com "       <--- not good
        }, 
        {
            "name": "3",
            "email": "Rezaul Hasan ",          <--- not good
            "mobile": "rezaul@gmail.com "      <--- not good
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd suggest you fix your JSON data first. `"Rezaul Hasan "` is really not an email ID, and `"rezaul@gmail.com "` is really not a cell-phone number.

Let me know if there are any questions! :)

Comment: String st = "<json data>";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

if i want to load json from a php url then what i do here ? Please help me :)

Comment: @Istiyak I'm not entirely clear about what you mean, or how this php file works. I'd suggest you write a new question to best address your problem.

Comment: Your answer is right also.
Actualy i make a Custom List View for my Project and there i use String value as item list value and now i want to load json from web as i encode json by php and want to save the json data to that string value. 
In a hand i just want to make a custom list view system with JSON parse from web.

Comment: Can i use that -  String st = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/568cf9120f00009542cceec5" for parsing JSON ? this is an example just

Comment: nope. you will have to download the json from the link first.

Comment: thanks for help me... i understand the process now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gson` library to deserialize json into Map (Or any java bean) and then populate the lists for emails and mobile numbers, e.g.:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> data = gson.fromJson("{\"server_response\": [{    \"name\": \"1\",    \"email\": \"istiyak.pro@gmail.com\",    \"mobile\": \"990-100010000\"}, {    \"name\": \"2\",    \"email\": \"Tanim Khan \",    \"mobile\": \"tanim@gmail.com \"}, {    \"name\": \"3\",    \"email\": \"Rezaul Hasan \",    \"mobile\": \"rezaul@gmail.com \"}]}", Map.class);
List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) data.get("server_response");
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, Object> element : list){
    emails.add(element.get("email").toString().trim());
    numbers.add(element.get("mobile").toString().trim());
}
System.out.println(emails);
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Comment: Map<String, Object> data = gson.fromJson();
Here i want to load json from a php url then what i do in that case ??? :)